# Scraping titles and dates

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am scraping "https://www.sbp.org.pk/ecodata/index2.asp" this website. My task is that to scrape those titles which update on daily basis and after that, I put them into data frames, and whenever I click on the title it shows me the pdf file. If someone knows my problem then please visit this website and then tell me.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas import DataFrame
    import datetime as dt
    url = "https://www.sbp.org.pk/ecodata/index2.asp"
    r=requests.get(url)
    htmlContent = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')
    soup
    
    gdp_table = []
    
    for a in soup.find_all("strong"):
        gdp_table.append(a.text)
    
    gdp_table1[3]='Last Updated'
    gdp_table1[4]='Data Archive'
    gdp_table1[5]='Archive Updated'
    gdp_table1
    val = []
    for b in soup.find_all("a"):
        val.append(b.text.strip())
    val
    val = list(filter(lambda x: x!= '', val))
    val[0:-24]
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col':gdp_table1})
    print (df)
    df1=df.T
    df1.columns = gdp_table1 #['a','b','c']
    df1
    data=[]
    for c in soup.find_all("td"):
        data.append(c.text.strip())
    data
    for i in val:
        df2 = df2.append({'Description': i}, ignore_index=True)
    data1 = [_.replace('\n', ' ') for _ in data1]
    for _ in data1:
        try:
            data_date = dt.datetime.strptime(_, '%b %d, %Y')
            print(data_date.date())
        except ValueError:
            continue

This is the code I Scrape all the titles and dates. Some title has no dates now i have to put it into one data frame and after that i want all the title that updated on daily basis in hyperlink form
```

Comment: Your question is little ambiguous. Clearly state the issue. However If I get your point, you want to fetch data on daily basis. For this you can compare the date available in the data table. And please show your attempt.

Comment: My question is that I want to scrape all the descriptions and all the dates that update on daily basis. After Scraping put the dates and description into the data frame. Some descriptions have no dates. The second thing to do is the description is in hyperlink form so when I click on it. it opens the updated pdf file

Comment: Yes I provided you the code now check this